# How do i find the total number of records created on a given day using T-SQL?

Tags: database, t-sql, grouping

I need to find out the total number of records that were created on a given day.

e.g.

**ID** **CreatedDate**
1  17/07/2009
2  12/07/2009
3  17/07/2009
4  05/07/2009
5  12/07/2009
6  17/07/2009

Output:

3 Records were created on 17/07/2009
2 Records were created on 12/07/2009
1 Record was created on 05/07/2009

**EDIT**

Upon testing the second suggestion made by Chris Roberts of including the formatting in the SQL i get this error:

```
Syntax error converting the varchar value ' Records were created on ' to a column of data type int.
```

Does anyone know how to rework the solution so that it works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to get the data you're after with the following SQL...

`SELECT COUNT(ID), CreatedDate
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY CreatedDate`

Or - if you want to do the formatting in the SQL, too...

`SELECT CONVERT(varchar, COUNT(ID)) + ' Records were created on ' + CONVERT(varchar, CreatedDate)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY CreatedDate`

Good luck!

Comment: I am getting an error when trying to perform the formatting within the SQL statement, see my edit.

Comment: I've just added the two 'CONVERT' statements into the second query - give that a go!

Answer (score 1):

Is the column actually a timestamp? In which case you will need to apply a function to remove the time component, e.g.:

SELECT COUNT(*), date(CreatedDate)  FROM MyTable GROUP BY date(CreatedDate)

I don't know what the function is in T-SQL, it's date() in MySQL and trunc() in Oracle. You may even have to do a to_string and remove the end of the string and group by that if you lack this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

```
select count(*), CreatedDate from table group by CreatedDate order by count(*) DESC
```

Comment: Shouldn't the GROUP BY be on the CreatedDate field?

Comment: -1 That won't even get past the syntax check.  Chris has got the right answer